# Isometries: Find the vectors and matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, rotations, isometry, reflection

We consider the isometries of $\Bbb R^2$. Let $\varphi$ be the rotation of $90^\circ$ (counterclockwise) around the point $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$ and let $\psi$ be the reflection about the line that is parallel to the $x$-axis through the point $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$.

- Determine $v\in\Bbb R^2,\ a\in O_2$ s. t. $\varphi=\tau_v\circ\varphi_a$.
- Determine $w\in\Bbb R^2$, $b\in O_2$ such that $\psi=\tau_w\circ\varphi_b$.
- Determine $u\in\Bbb R^2,\ c\in O_2$ s. t.$\psi\circ\varphi=\tau_u\circ\varphi_c$.

$$$$

For the first one we have that: $$(\tau_v\circ\varphi_a)(x)=\tau_v(\varphi_a(x))=\tau_v(ax)=ax+v$$ And this has to be equal to the vector $x$ rotated by $90^\circ$ counterclockwise around the point $\begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 5\end{pmatrix}$, right?

So do we have to use the matrix for the map of rotation?

Comment: Is $\psi$ supposed to be a reflection?

Comment: From the nature of the question, I suspect that you are meant to use the $3 \times 3$ matrices corresponding to these [affine transformations in homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Affine_transformations).

Comment: It is not clear what $O_2$ means here (as in $a \in O_2$), nor what $\phi_a$ is supposed to represent. I see that you have assumed that $\phi_a(x) := ax$, but if this were the case and $a$ is a scalar then $\phi = \tau_v \circ \phi_a$ has no solution.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that $O_2$ refers to the set of $2 \times 2$ orthogonal matrices, so that $a$ for instance is meant to represent a $2 \times 2$ matrix. Here's an approach that avoids using homogeneous coordinates, contrary to the suggestions of my comment.

Let $r_{\theta}$ denote the matrix corresponding to the counterclockwise rotation by angle $\theta$. Note (or show) that the rotation $\phi(x)$ satisfies
$$
\phi(x) = r_{90^\circ}(x - (3,5)^T) + (3,5)^T.
$$
Expand the multiplication above to obtain an expression of the form $ax + v$, which gives you the answer to the first part.

For part 2, note similarly that if $f_{(a,b)}$ denotes the reflection across the line through $0$ in the direction of $(a,b)^T$, then we can write
$$
\psi(x) = f_{(1,0)}(x - (0,1)^T) + (0,1)^T.
$$

Comment: At part 1 we have : $$\phi(x) = r_{90^\circ}(x - (3,5)^T) + (3,5)^T= r_{90^\circ}x+(I- r_{90^\circ})(3,5)^T=\tau_{(I- r_{90^\circ})(3,5)^T}( r_{90^\circ}x)=(\tau_{(I- r_{90^\circ})(3,5)^T}\circ \phi_{ r_{90^\circ}})(x)$$ Right?

Comment: At the second part do we have that $(a,b)=(1,0)$ because the direction has to be parallel to the $x$-axis?

Comment: @Mary The answer to both questions is yes. Note that we can explicitly calculate
$$
(3,5)^T - r_{90^\circ}(3,5)^T = (3,5)^T - (-5,3)^T = (8,2)^T.
$$

Comment: Ahh ok! And at the second part, the matrix $f$ of the rotation is in this case $=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & - 1\end{pmatrix}$, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar The transformation in the second part is not a rotation. But yes, that is the correct matrix.